How to fill a barplot, not according to the occurences of an element in a dataset, but according to its value in another variable? See example
Imagine having this dataset:
Country Energy_Source Twh   Tot
Italy   Biofuel        24.5 100
Italy   Nuclear        15.4 100
Italy   Gas            40.1 100
Italy   Hydro          20.0 100
France  Biofuel        20.0 120
France  Nuclear        75.0 120
France  Gas            10.0 120
France  Hydro          4.3  120
France  Wind           10.7 120   

Note: Tot is the sum of Twh by Country
dataset1 <- data.frame(
  "Country" = c(rep(x = "Italy", times = 4), rep(x = "France", times = 5)),
  "Energy_Source" = c("Biofuel", "Nuclear", "Gas", "Hydro", "Biofuel", "Nuclear", "Gas", "Hydro", "Wind"),
  "Twh" = c(25, 15, 40, 20, 20, 75, 10, 5, 10),
  "Tot" = c(rep(x = 100, times = 4), rep(x = 120, times = 5))
)

Now, we want ggplot2 to interpret this dataset1 as if it was like the following (dataset2) without performing a pivot_longer on dataset1
Here the new dataset2 that represents exactly the same informations as dataset1 but with duplicates for ggplot2 to interpret the occurences of each element as a proportion
Country Energy_Source Twh Tot
Italy   Biofuel        25 100
Italy   Biofuel        25 100
Italy   Biofuel        25 100
.
.
. (22 more rows)
Italy   Nuclear        15 100
. (14 more rows)
Italy   Gas            40 100
. (etcetera)

dataset2 <- data.frame(
   "Country" = c(rep(x = "Italy", times = 100), rep(x = "France", times = 120)),
   "Energy_Source" = c(rep(x = "Biofuel", times = 25), rep(x = "Nuclear", times = 15),
   rep(x = "Gas", times = 40), rep(x = "Hydro", times = 20), rep(x = "Biofuel", times = 20),
   rep(x = "Nuclear", times = 75), rep(x = "Gas", times = 10), rep(x = "Hydro", times = 5),
   rep(x = "Wind", times = 10)),
   "Tot" = c(rep(x = 100, times = 100), rep(x = 120, times = 120))
 )

Now, normally we would use the following code to represent the barplots
ggplot(data = dataset2, mapping = aes(
                                   x = Tot, 
                                   y = reorder(Country, Tot), 
                                   fill = Energy_Source
                                 )) +
  geom_col()


See here:

But is it possible to use dataset1 and not dataset2 to create the same graph with ggplot2?
In other terms:
How to fill a barplot, not according to the occurences of an element in a dataset, but according to its value in another variable?
Thanks!
I tried performing a pivot_longer from the tidyr package but it was too costly for my Shiny App.

Would x = Tot*Twh, suffice inside aes() to show bars that reflect the product of Tot & Twh? Or if you want separate plotted bars for each observation (which you have in your plot but invisibly), you could use data = dataset |> tidyr::uncount(Twh)

Thanks for your response but it does not really answer my question. Maybe i wasn't totally clear about what i want to perform, i have rewritten my question. Do not hesitate to tell if my question remains ambiguous.

I am using dataset1 in two ways to recreate your plot. Please help me understand if/how that's different from what you're looking for.

Here are two ways to recreate your plot using dataset1.

Scale in proportion to Twh. This seems simplest and most efficient, provided you don't need the visible bars to be composed of many stacked smaller bars.


ggplot(dataset1, aes(
  x = Tot*Twh, 
  y = reorder(Country, Tot), 
  fill = Energy_Source
)) +
  geom_col()



tidyr::uncount is what you want if you want to make copies of each observation. This replicates your dataset2 approach. I have added borders to show how this makes many small bars that are stacked together. This approach is fine here, but I've had issues where it might plot very slowly (e.g. if >100k observations to plot), or plot messily (e.g. if the borders overwhelm the areas or create moire effects), or inefficiently (e.g. a vector format like PDF would save a separate object for each bar plotted, even if <1 pixel).


ggplot(dataset1 |> tidyr::uncount(Twh), aes(
  x = Tot, 
  y = reorder(Country, Tot), 
  fill = Energy_Source
)) +
  geom_col(color = "gray50")



Edit: For the OP's description of "sequential" data, I think it's more efficient computationally and cleaner to plot if you calculate the aggregations (here, the average usage across years of energy source per country) with a dplyr step.
Compare a version of what's in the OP's suggested answer:
rbind(dataset1, dataset1b) |>
  mutate(across(Twh, ~.x * 10)) |>
  uncount(Twh) |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Tot / (10 * 2), 
    y = reorder(Country, Tot), 
    fill = Energy_Source
  )) +
  geom_col()

...to a version using dplyr. Same superficial visual appearance, except the uncount version plots 4,400 observations, vs. the dplyr version just plots the 9 contiguous bars we can see.
rbind(dataset1, dataset1b) |>
  summarize(Total = mean(Tot * Twh), .by = c(Country, Energy_Source)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Total,
    y = reorder(Country, Total), 
    fill = Energy_Source
  )) +
  geom_col()


For reference, your example plot with the same dimensions:


Many thanks.
Now i see where i should have been more precise.
First, for the method with tidyr::uncount() it is great, but does not work with decimal value, it is my fault i should have put an example in my dataset.
Second, the method with Twh*Tot works great until we work with sequential data.
I will rewrite my question.
Sorry for my abiguous question, appreciate the help.

Jon Spring answer is great.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/6851825/jon-spring?tab=profile
Now, to go further if you have a sequential dataset with decimal values to the variables you are working with (and you do not want to round them), here is how to deal with it:
Example dataset:
dataset1 <- data.frame(
  "Country" = c(rep(x = "Italy", times = 4), rep(x = "France", times = 5)),
  "Energy_Source" = c("Biofuel", "Nuclear", "Gas", "Hydro", "Biofuel", "Nuclear", "Gas", "Hydro", "Wind"),
  "Twh" = c(24.3, 15.7, 40.0, 20.0, 19.1, 75.9, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0),
  "Tot" = c(rep(x = 100, times = 4), rep(x = 120, times = 5)),
  "Year" = c(rep(x = 2012, times = 9))
)

dataset1b <- data.frame(
  "Country" = c(rep(x = "Italy", times = 4), rep(x = "France", times = 5)),
  "Energy_Source" = c("Biofuel", "Nuclear", "Gas", "Hydro", "Biofuel", "Nuclear", "Gas", "Hydro", "Wind"),
  "Twh" = c(25.0, 15.0, 40.0, 20.8, 19.2, 75.0, 10.0, 5.0, 10.0),
  "Tot" = c(rep(x = 100, times = 4), rep(x = 120, times = 5)),
  "Year" = c(rep(x = 2013, times = 9))
)

dataset1 <- rbind(dataset1, dataset1b)
head(dataset1, n = 10)

##    Country Energy_Source  Twh Tot Year
## 1    Italy       Biofuel 24.3 100 2012
## 2    Italy       Nuclear 15.7 100 2012
## 3    Italy           Gas 40.0 100 2012
## 4    Italy         Hydro 20.0 100 2012
## 5   France       Biofuel 19.1 120 2012
## 6   France       Nuclear 75.9 120 2012
## 7   France           Gas 10.0 120 2012
## 8   France         Hydro  5.0 120 2012
## 9   France          Wind 10.0 120 2012
## 10   Italy       Biofuel 25.0 100 2013


Note: Tot represents the sum(Twh) by Country
First, multiply the Twh column with a round number that will transform all of the decimals to int. In the example, none of the values has more than one number after the 0, so we multiply Twh by 10, let's called it multiplicator
multiplicator <- 10
dataset1$Twh <- dataset1$Twh * multiplicator
head(dataset1)
##   Country Energy_Source Twh Tot Year
## 1   Italy       Biofuel 243 100 2012
## 2   Italy       Nuclear 157 100 2012
## 3   Italy           Gas 400 100 2012
## 4   Italy         Hydro 200 100 2012
## 5  France       Biofuel 191 120 2012
## 6  France       Nuclear 759 120 2012

Second, we apply the tidyr::uncount() function to dataset1 with Twh as a parameter, it is the variable that will dupplicate each row according to its value at each row.
dataset1 <- dataset1 |> tidyr::uncount(Twh)
##   Country Energy_Source Tot Year
## 1   Italy       Biofuel 100 2012
## 2   Italy       Biofuel 100 2012
## 3   Italy       Biofuel 100 2012
## 4   Italy       Biofuel 100 2012
## 5   Italy       Biofuel 100 2012
## 6   Italy       Biofuel 100 2012

Finally we plot the data using ggplot2 as following:
ggplot(dataset1, aes(
  x = Tot / (multiplicator * length(unique(dataset1$Year))), 
  y = reorder(Country, Tot), 
  fill = Energy_Source
)) +
  geom_col()

See:

As ggplot2 understands the proportion of each element by their occurence in a dataset and that multiplicator and the non grouping column wich is Year affected the occurence, we divide Tot by (multiplicator * length(unique(dataset1$Year))).

See my edited answer. I only provided the uncount approach in case there is a compelling reason that you want to plot every observation separately -- perhaps because there is further labeling on those, or you want the user to be able to perceive the observations more viscerally (ie almost like a waffle chart). If the purpose is just a means of aggregation, dplyr::summarize is a more effective approach, and will avoid potential plotting issues.
